# Mongoose Model.save() hangs when called from node.js app

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I'm trying to learn node and mongo in order to build a simple web app/teach myself a little bit more about web applications. However, when I call Model.save(), the continuation function never seems to execute, and the data isn't saved.

Here's what I have so far:

```
/* app.js */

var express = require('express')
  , app = express()
  , routes = require('./routes')
  , http = require('http')
  , path = require('path')
  , mongoose = require('mongoose')
  , db 
  , Track
  , models = require('./models.js');

app.configure(function(){
  app.set('port', process.env.PORT || 3000);
  app.set('views', __dirname + '/views');
  app.set('view engine', 'ejs');
  app.use(express.favicon());
  app.use(express.logger('dev'));
  app.use(express.bodyParser());
  app.use(express.methodOverride());
  app.use(express.cookieParser('secretstuff'));
  app.use(express.session());
  app.use(app.router);
  app.use(require('less-middleware')({ src: __dirname + '/public' }));
  app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
  app.use(function(err, req, res, next){
    console.error(err.stack);
    res.send(500, 'Something broke!');
  });
});

models.defineModels(mongoose, function(){
  app.Track = Track = mongoose.model('Track');
  db = mongoose.createConnection('localhost','nextrak')
});

app.get('/', routes.index);

app.get('/dbTest', function(req, res){
  console.log("Here goes...");
  var t = new Track({
    name: "TestTrack",
    artist: "Artist",
    tags: ["test"],
    next: ["track1","track2"]
  });
  console.log("Test Track:");
  console.log(t);

  t.save(function(){
    if(err)
      console.log("Error! Couldn't complete dbTest successfully.");
    else
      console.log("Aw yiss, got dbTest working");
  })
});

http.createServer(app).listen(app.get('port'), function(){
  console.log("Express server listening on port " + app.get('port'));
});


/*models.js*/

function defineModels(mongoose, cont){
  var Schema = mongoose.Schema;
  Track = new Schema({
    'name': { type: String, index: true },
    'artist': String,
    'tags': [String],
    'next': [String],
  });
  mongoose.model('Track', Track);
  cont();
}

exports.defineModels = defineModels;
```

No errors are thrown, and the mongo logs indicate that 5 new connections are spun up when I launch my app. No new logs appear (except [clientcursormon] logs). The app prints out the following when I load /dbTest in Chrome:

Here goes...

```
  Test Track:
    { name: 'TestTrack',
      artist: 'Basik',
      _id: 5031606aa11cf95815000001,
      next: [ 'track1', 'track2' ],
      tags: [ 'test' ] }
```

Mongo appears to be configured correctly. When I have node run the simple "Getting Started" script that Mongoose walks you through, everything works correctly.

Can anyone point out what I'm doing incorrectly?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You haven't created a connection for Mongoose to use by default.  Replace this:

```
db = mongoose.createConnection('localhost','nextrak')
```

With this:

```
db = mongoose.connect('localhost', 'nextrak');
```

Couple other nits:

1. You're setting `Track` as a global variable in models.js
2. You need to add a `err` parameter to your `t.save` callback.

Comment: Thanks a bunch. Now, since using mongoose.connect() sets that connection as default, do I even need to bind the result of that call to db? And good catch on the two bugs.

Comment: @Salem Typically yes, so that you can properly disconnect during shutdown using `db.disconnect();`

Comment: The default express generator uses the old version. Hours of pain because of this!

Answer (score 2):

First of all, if you only need one connection, you should use mongoose.connect().

Second, I think you're mixing up the track schema and track model. These are two separate things. new Schema() create a Schema object, which gets passed to mongoose.model(). The result of mongoose.model (which it seems you're discarding) is what you want to use when creating a new instance to store in the database, not the schema.

Comment: I'm not sure I follow. I thought I was using the schema to create the model, and then call the model when I needed it: 

  app.Track = Track = mongoose.model('Track');

So, wouldn't a new Track be a new model, to which you pass an object representing the data?

Comment: Yes, but you're using the same variable for the Schema, which is confusing. I'm also not sure why you're calling mongoose.model twice, once inside defineModels and once outside. At any rate, you need to use mongoose.connect() and call that *before* you make the model.

Comment: Ah, I understand. I've been essentially pulling apart someone else's open source app to try and figure out how to do simple CRUD-type stuff. I'm still a bit confused as to why they define db and never seem to use it. At any rate, thanks!